# programmatically vibrate non stop

Tags: android, android-vibration

I have a BroadcastReceiver in my android application.
I want to vibrate when something special happen in my Receiver.

I know how to control vibrate, but there are 2 problems:

1- When power button pressed and screen gets off device stops vibrating.
2- After turning on Screen again if my vibration repeat parameter set to more than 1 it never vibrate again.

here is my vibration method:

```
public void startVibrate(Context context, int repeat) {
    vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    int dot = 200;          // Length of a Morse Code "dot" in milliseconds
    int dash = 500;         // Length of a Morse Code "dash" in milliseconds
    int short_gap = 200;    // Length of Gap Between dots/dashes
    int medium_gap = 500;   // Length of Gap Between Letters
    int long_gap = 1000;    // Length of Gap Between Words
    long[] pattern = {
            0,  // Start immediately
            dot, short_gap, dot, short_gap, dot, medium_gap,    // S
            dash, short_gap, dash, short_gap, dash, medium_gap, // O
            dot, short_gap, dot, short_gap, dot, long_gap       // S
    };
    vibrator.vibrate(pattern, repeat);
    //vibrator.vibrate(10000);
}
```

here is vibration method call:

```
controller.startVibrate(context, 0);
```

Comment: I just have to ask... Why? This seems like a bad idea from the users perspective. Not to mention a battery killer.

Comment: Are you sure that you want your users to make **VooDoo dolls** with your name and put nails in them because **you drain** their device's **battery**?

Comment: dudes please answer and don't judge my app.

Comment: try to change the repeat value to zero.

Answer (score 2):

I know  i am answering very late but it might help anyone so if you don't want to repeat pattern you pass -1 to repeat pattern.

Vibrator.vibrate(pattern, -1);

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html

Comment: That method has been deprecated as of API 26 (Oreo)